# iPhone freezes for >30s whenever I install or update an app

Tags: iphone, ios, performance

### Issue

Whenever I install or upgrade an app after the install step (but before the app is able to launch) my device freezes for between 30s - and a couple of minutes (worst case).  During this, it's unresponsive to home button pushes, swipes, etc.  After the time passes, it resumes function as normal.

### What I've tried

Rebooting, upgrading iOS to latest -- And perhaps most informing, this issue has followed me through 3 phones (2 iPhone 7, and one iPhone X) -- It seems to be with something that gets backed up, so that when I restore from backup the issue then persists.

Note -- It also freezes after I install apps using xcode development.  In this case, the freeze is long enough that X-Code thinks that the build has failed and gives me the message "iPhone has denied the launch request." -- But eventually it launches anyway (after the freeze part)

Comment: Is it an option for you to just wipe your iPhone and set it up again but **not** restore it from a backup?

Comment: @fsb ... A real pain, but may be what I resort to.  I was hoping to ask here and see if it's a known bug.

Comment: It's not a bug that I know of.  I have experienced issues restoring from backups instead of setting-up as a new device, however.  That might be your best option.